# Vista + VB.NET - Access is denied while trying to start/stop a Windows Service from within an application

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, windows-vista, service, vista-security

I get the following error in Vista while trying to start/stop a Windows Service that I created.

```
Cannot open ServiceName service on computer '.'.
```

The same code works for XP. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

User Account Control (aka UAC).  UAC means that the user is not running as an administrator.  Your application needs to tell windows that it requires admin rights.  I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) page explains it better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon your question today, though you had asked it a while back :)
I was having a similar problem on Windows Vista while i was trying to start a .net based service that i had developed.
I opened the Properties dialog of the service and changed the Log On user to Local System (Previously i was trying to start the service using Network Service). On restarting the service i didn't get any error.
In case you are still wondering about the answer, this has worked for me. I hope it will work for you too.
Cheers!